# How do I create a back button in excel

Tags: vba, microsoft-excel-2013

I need to create a back button in excel, which allows the user to go back to the previously viewed worksheet. Not sure how to do this in VBA, any thoughts would be appreciated.

Thanks, Dave.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is done in the Visual Basic Editor (Alt + F11).

In any standard module, at the very top (below any Option statements you may have) put this ....

Code:

```
Public strLastSheet As String
```

in a worksheet module, copy the following code:

Code:

```
Sub GotoLastSheet()
On Error Resume Next
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strLastSheet).Activate
End Sub
```

Enter the following code in the ThisWorkbook module of your workbook.

Code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
strLastSheet = Sh.Name
End Sub
```

On the developer tab click insert button (blank box in form controls). Assign the macro:
“…GotoLastSheet”

You are done. Rename the button to "Back". 
Hope this helps, Ted